# railsで検索フォームを作っていたのですが、UrlGenerationErrorが出て、躓いております。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

コードは主に以下になります。

こちらで、'members#index'にアクセスした時点でエラーが出ております。

`No route matches {:action=>"search", :controller=>"members"} missing required keys: [:tweet_form]`

ルーティングがおかしいのだということはわかるのですが、
それに対し、どのように修正したら良いのかがわかりません。

route.rbのコードを一時的に以下のようにして試し
`get '/' => 'members#search', as: 'search'`

検索ボタンを押下すると、以下のようなurlが発行されました。

`search?utf8=✓&tweet_form%5Btweet%5D=ほげ&commit=検索`

このようなルーティングを設定するにはどうすればよいか途方に暮れております・・・。
（「ほげ」が検索ワードです。）

宜しければ、ご指摘願えないでしょうか？

※検索用のgemもありますが、今回はgem抜きで実装したく思っております。

app/models/tweet_form.rb

```
class TweetForm
  include Virtus

  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attribute :tweet, String

  #これがないとエラーが出る。
  #undefined method `persisted?
  def persisted? ; false ; end

  def search
    scoped = Tweet.all
    scoped = Tweet.where("tweet LIKE ?", "%#{tweet}%") if tweet.present?
    scoped
  end
end
```

controllers/members_controller.rb

```
  def search
    @tweet_form = TweetForm.new params[:tweet_form]
    @tweets = @tweet_form.search
    render :index
  end
```

views/members/index.html.slim

```
= form_for @tweet_form, url: search_path, method: :get do |f|
  .form-group
    = f.text_field :tweet
  = f.submit '検索', class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

config/route.rb

```
  root_to: 'members#index'
  get '/:tweet_form' => 'members#search', as: 'search'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
get '/search' => 'members#search', as: 'search'
```

のように書くと解決しそうな気がしますが、どうでしょうか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
頂いたルーティングで動作致しました。
自分で問題をすごく複雑にしてしまってました・・・。

感謝申し上げます。

Comment: 解決したようで良かったです！で、解決した場合は回答を承認してください。（緑色のチェックマークを付ける）承認しないと永遠に未解決の質問になってしまうので。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 回答を承認させて頂きました。stackoverflowはじめて承認機能があることが知りませんでした・・・。教えて頂きありがとうございます！

Comment: 承認ありがとうございます！スタック・オーバーフローの使い方については以前自分のブログに書いたので、こちらもよかったら参考にしてみてください => http://blog.jnito.com/entry/2015/10/04/073825